# What does the ranker in Weka PCA tell us about feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, weka, pca, feature-selection

I have a data set that is 31000 rows with 13 attributes. But because most are categorical I had to use NominalToBinary for those attributes so the attributes grew to 61.

I have sampled the data to 18000 rows and applied the PCA with ranker in Weka. centerData is false so it should normalise it for me.

This is my result:

```
 0.945     1 -0.367Marial_Status= Married-civ-spouse-0.365Relationship= Husband+0.298Marial_Status= Never-married+0.244Age=0_23+0.232Gender= Female...
```

I understand that the ranking is the variance. So rank 1 is 94.5%? Now the issue I have with feature selecting is how do i know which ones to keep? Most of these attributes are categorical and changed to numeric for the PCA. So with the original data-set with both categorical and numeric, with respects to this output what is it saying about feature selecting?

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote you, but if you're going to blame me for it, I probably should but your question is 1) a direct violation of SO policy which I both outlined for you and linked for you and 2) is one vote away from being closed for the reason I commented on. So you can either follow the rules and show the code as text or allow your question to be removed altogether.

Comment: @Rob I changed the format. I think you could at least tell me policy I broke which you did and then help answer the question or provide some assistance. I changed the image to code format so not sure why it would be closed? Plus why was my comment removed?

Comment: After you read [ask], you can now read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or at least  [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were given to read when you originally signed up for SO.

Comment: @Rob "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." I think this sums up my question well. I've attempted to explain the concept and just need more clarification

Comment: Please don't address me. This is not my area of expertise. It was presented to me on a list of questions to review.

Answer (score 0):

PCA assumes numerical data. If you binary encode you categorical variables you basically take a hammer and make you data fit your models assumption.

Another way to deal with categorical features are non-linear feature transformations which will find a way to represent distances between categories in a suitable way. A quick google search provided Categorical Principal Components Analysis (CTPCA) for me. Maybe have a look at this.